# javascript - extract text from value and add to new key value pair

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

I am getting the below data object back in response to a fetch request.  Does anyone know of a function that can extract the three numbers in the .ref property and add it to a new key value pair after SUBTOTAL called Code: 011 and Code: 005 if we're using my example below.  So I'd have a new object with this additional key value pair and the values from ref.

```
[
  {
    ref: 'COS-MOD-011-CDT-PRP-3521234893',
    fra: 'XX ',
    batchref: 3181,
    F_NAME: 'Bee',
    L_NAME: 'Boker',
    M_NUMBER: '33411245596X',
    CREATED: '2020-12-21T10:33:57',
    PRODUCT: 'XYZ',
    OPTION: '2 Tickets',
    PRICE: 12,
    QTY: 2,
    SUBTOTAL: 24
  },
  {
    ref: 'COS-MOD-005-CDT-PRP-3521234893',
    fra: 'XX ',
    batchref: 3181,
    F_NAME: 'Baa',
    L_NAME: 'Beep',
    M_NUMBER: '312334596X',
    CREATED: '2020-12-21T10:33:57',
    PRODUCT: 'XYZ',
    OPTION: '2 Tickets',
    PRICE: 12,
    QTY: 2,
    SUBTOTAL: 24
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that ?

```js
const data = 
      [ { ref      : 'COS-MOD-011-CDT-PRP-3521234893'
        , fra      : 'XX '
        , batchref : 3181
        , F_NAME   : 'Bee'
        , L_NAME   : 'Boker'
        , M_NUMBER : '33411245596X'
        , CREATED  : '2020-12-21T10:33:57'
        , PRODUCT  : 'XYZ'
        , OPTION   : '2 Tickets'
        , PRICE    : 12
        , QTY      : 2
        , SUBTOTAL : 24
        } 
      , { ref      : 'COS-MOD-005-CDT-PRP-3521234893'
        , fra      : 'XX '
        , batchref : 3181
        , F_NAME   : 'Baa'
        , L_NAME   : 'Beep'
        , M_NUMBER : '312334596X'
        , CREATED  : '2020-12-21T10:33:57'
        , PRODUCT  : 'XYZ'
        , OPTION   : '2 Tickets'
        , PRICE    : 12
        , QTY      : 2
        , SUBTOTAL : 24
        } 
      ] 

const newData = data.map(({ref,...more})=>({ref,...more,Code:ref.split('-')[2]}))


console.log( newData )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure where exactly you want `SUBTOTAL` to be but if `ref` is always that format you can simply just do

```js
let ref_value = obj_name.ref.split("-")[2]
```

JSFiddle with the relevant code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p59o3azw/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  {
    ref: 'COS-MOD-011-CDT-PRP-3521234893',
    fra: 'XX ',
    batchref: 3181,
    F_NAME: 'Bee',
    L_NAME: 'Boker',
    M_NUMBER: '33411245596X',
    CREATED: '2020-12-21T10:33:57',
    PRODUCT: 'XYZ',
    OPTION: '2 Tickets',
    PRICE: 12,
    QTY: 2,
    SUBTOTAL: 24
  },
  {
    ref: 'COS-MOD-005-CDT-PRP-3521234893',
    fra: 'XX ',
    batchref: 3181,
    F_NAME: 'Baa',
    L_NAME: 'Beep',
    M_NUMBER: '312334596X',
    CREATED: '2020-12-21T10:33:57',
    PRODUCT: 'XYZ',
    OPTION: '2 Tickets',
    PRICE: 12,
    QTY: 2,
    SUBTOTAL: 24
  }
]

array.forEach(e => e.Code = e.ref.match(/...-...-(\d\d\d)-.*/)[1])

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let obj.code = obj.ref.slice(7, 10);
```

slice will return the string between the position 7 until the position 10 of your .ref property.